# Sphinx internationalization issue

Tags: python, internationalization, python-sphinx

I am using *Sphinx* in documentation to generate *HTML* files from rst input. I currently have the following directory structure,

**Option 1**

```
|-- source
|   |-- content
|   |   `-- translated
|   |       `-- si
|   |           `-- LC_MESSAGES
|   |-- images
```

conf.py file is inside source directory and rst files are inside content directory. I have set `locale_dirs=['content/translated/']` in conf.py.

The issue is that when I generated the HTML files the translations are not there.

This works fine with the following directory structure,

**Option 2**

```
|-- source
|-- translated
|   |-- si
|   |    -- LC_MESSAGES
|-- images
```

In this case rst files are inside source directory and the `locale_dirs=['translated/']` in conf.py.

I cannot figure out why **Option 1** is not working. Any help is highly appreciated.